# How to see docker image layers when image tag is not present

Tags: docker, docker-image, docker-cli

I was trying various options of `"docker image history"` command to see the image layers used to build the image on my local machine.

There is a nginx image on my system which has no tags assigned. So `"docker images"` command lists the following images in my system.

[image]

I tried to find layer details for nginx image using following command :

```
docker image history nginx
```

But as the tag name is not specified, docker-cli considers it default "**latest**" tag which is not present on my system and I am getting following error :

```
Error response from daemon: No such image: nginx:latest
```

I tried the same command with "**none**" as tag but it also failed with following error :

```
docker image history nginx:none
Error response from daemon: No such image: nginx:none
```

Any suggestions ? How can we see layers of an images which does not have tag assigned.

Comment: Do you mean to use `docker tag nginx nginx:latest` to retag it?

Comment: The questions is not about  tagging an image. It is on how to inspect image layers of an untagged image.

Comment: since the image lacks any tag, I recommended re-tag it. The error is with image having `none` tag is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `--filter` option for `docker images` command which we can use to find **dangling/untagged** images as below :

```
docker images -f "dangling=true" --quiet
```

We can use this command to list image layers for the untagged image as below :

```
docker image history  $(docker images -f "dangling=true" --quiet)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using ID instead of name with tag.

Let say that I have this output of `docker images`

```
REPOSITORY TAG      IMAGE ID       CREATED      SIZE
postgres   <none>   1f0815c1cb6e   7 weeks ago  314M
```

I can use `docker image history` and specify the ID or part of it sufficient to identify the image in this context.

```
docker image history 1f0
```

Comment: yes, it is working with id. But I was looking for some alternative solution in case I want to use image name.

Answer (score 1):

```
docker history <your-docker-image-id>
```

In your case it is as follows:

```
docker history 7ce4f91ef623
```

Comment: yes, it is working with id. But I was looking for some alternative solution in case I want to use image name.